# Confusuion with trivial solution to a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following question here:

> Find all vectors $\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b \end{pmatrix}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the solution to the linear system with augmented matrix
> $\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 1&2\;&\;a\\ 3&2\;&\;b\end{array}\right)$
> is the vector $\begin{pmatrix}-a\\ -b \end{pmatrix}$.

This question really confuses me. So my approach was to do row reduction and make the solution equal to $\begin{pmatrix}-a\\ -b \end{pmatrix}$.

So row reducing, we get:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  1 & 0 \;&\; a-2\left(\frac{b-3a}{4} \right)\\ 0 & 1 \;&\; \frac{b-3a}{4}
\end{array}\right)$$

So that means we have $a-2\left(\frac{b-3a}{4} \right)=-a$ and $\frac{b-3a}{4}=-b$. Simplifying, we get:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{7}{2}a - \frac{1}{2}b &= 0 \\[3pt]
-\frac{3}{4}a + \frac{5}{4}b &= 0 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
So this gives $a=0,\, b=0$ as the only solution. Does that seem right? It feels off to get a trivial answer as the solution.

Comment: Another approach is to insert $-a$ and $-b$ for $x$ and $y$ and to solve the resulting equation system.

Comment: That $a=b=0$ is a solution is trivial. The augmented matrix has a zero column as last column so the corresponding linear system has the trivial solution. So why do you doubt the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your approach *should* work, you've made an arithmetic error. Here's a slightly different approach.

In order for $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} -a \\ -b \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ to be a solution to the linear system, we must be able to substitute in $x=-a$ and $y=-b$:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
1(-a) + 2(-b) &= a \\[2pt]
3(-a) + 2(-b) &= b 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
i.e.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
-2a - 2b &= 0 \\[2pt]
-3a - 3b &= 0 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

This is a singular system whose solution set is a $1$-dimensional subspace. *Solve it yourself before revealing.*

> $$ \operatorname{span} \biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \biggr\} = \biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} -t \\ t \end{pmatrix} \biggm| t \in \mathbb{R} \biggr\} $$

Comment: Ohh thank you! That actually makes a lot of sense! I guess I didn't realize you could go backwards at the start like that.